Matrix derivative of matrix commutator
I'm working on some functional and I have to calculate its second derivative with respect to some matrix-variables. I'm just left with the following derivative to perform:
$$
V''= -6 i \lambda \gamma f \dfrac{\delta}{\delta \phi^1}\big([\phi^2,\phi^3]\big)^T+ \lambda^2\dfrac{\delta}{\delta\phi^1}\big([[\phi^1,\phi^2],\phi^2]^T + [[\phi^1,\phi^3],\phi^3]^T\big)
$$
where $T$ stands for transpose. It seems to me the first term will just vanish, but I'm not sure about the second one: if I was to expand the commutators I'd get a bunch of $\delta (\phi^1)^T/\delta\phi^1 $ multiplying, for example, $\phi^2 \phi^2 - \phi^2\phi^2$, therefore getting zero there as well.
Is it so?
The problem with this result is that in this way I might be getting a $V'' = 0$ for every $\phi$, hence concluding $V$ must be linear in $\phi$, but I have already found a couple of minima of $V'=0$, so I'm sure it can not be.
Do you have any ideas?
Thank you!
